# jQuery: How to escape single and double quotes with backslash

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to escape single and double quotes with a backslash in one line rather than two.

Example for single quote:

```
str = str.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
```

Is there a way to do this at the same time for double quotes included?

Sniffer Answered this very well below, and I ended up escaping all characters we needed as follows:

```
str = str.replace(/(['"&:;])/g, "\\$1");
```

Thanks again Sniffer for the quick response!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try this:

```
str = str.replace(/(['"])/g, "\\$1");
```

Comment: Stackoverflow made me wait 10 minutes to click the green check... No one ever answers that fast lol

Comment: @no1uknow Sorry I didn't know that and thank you so much for accepting the answer and the kind words.